# Why does the native 'data' object not become masked by my assignment?

Tags: r, object, autocomplete, rstudio, masking

I'm using **Rstudio and R 3.2.4** and wondering why, when

```
data <- mtcars; data$cyl <- factor(data$cyl); contrasts(data$cyl)
```

R's code-completion (upong typing `data`and hitting `$`) reverts to thinking the `data` object is the one loaded with base R, not the assignment I've made in the first statement.  I can see this because hitting TAB shows all the datasets available in that object.

Why does the base `data` object not get masked?

Comment: Don't confuse your IDE behaviour with real R behaviour. You don't mention which IDE you use, so difficult to comment

Comment: @Andrie too right, apologies.  Updated in first line.

Comment: FWIW, I can confirm this crummy behavior by doing the following in Rstudio: `data <- mtcars; data$cyl <- factor(data$cyl); contrasts(data$cyl)`. (Maybe edit your question to use this as the minimal reproducible example?)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien derp.  fair enough :(

Comment: Using R 3..2.3 patched from terminal in Linux produces expected results: tabbing brings up the variable names.